# SharePoint date field value using jQuery

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery-ajax

[image]I have the input type as text for the date field and I am confused how to store the same in a variable and on change of that date function need to populate other column values SharePoint list. I need to populate values based on two field changes in SharePoint list. i.e on selection of both field certain fields should populate. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: The input value can be got with Jquery: var test=$("input[title='Date']").val();
And what is your requirement to populate value based on two fields change, did you want populate other column control in the new form once the date changed ?

Comment: Yes and also I need to combine meaning on change of date and one more column other fields should populate. like for example. on change of col A and col B   The  col C, Col D , Col E should be updated. These get updated based on the ajax call which is calling the rest api.

Comment: Add rest api code in DatePickerChanged function below, I think it will meet your requirement.

Comment: I need to store one more value in a variable and use both values in the variable as input to the api. I am using the (.change(function()). I am confused how to use two functions in one? Can you please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input value can be got with Jquery:

```
var test=$("input[title='Date']").val();
```

And you could trace the value change for this date field control in the new form like this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[title="Date"]').get(0).onvaluesetfrompicker=DatePickerChanged;    
});

function DatePickerChanged() {
    // Do stuff

    alert("value changed");
}
</script>
```

Write your populate logic code in DatePickerChanged function.

Comment: I need to store one more value in a variable and use both values in the variable as input to the api. I am using the (.change(function()). I am confused how to use two functions in one?

Comment: Per my test, .change() function won't trace the Date Control change event in SharePoint, you will need onvaluesetfrompicker like above. Have you tested my code above in SP List form?

Comment: yes I have tested and its working. but i have one more function need to called. ie on change of col1 + col2, rest of the columns should be populated.  I have a seperate function i.e change.function written to trigger the same.

Comment: Is there a way I can just pull the date value and store in a variable in the change function which I have already written?

Comment: You can store the date control value like I said above var test=$("input[title='Date']").val();, define a global variable in your code beginning.

Comment: okay thanks. I have the format as mm-dd-yyyy  when I select the date from SharePoint but my api takes input request as yyyy-mm-dd. How do I convert before passing the var value to api?

Comment: Convert like this:
var date = "03-11-2014";
var newdate = date.split("-").reverse().join("-");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83022/discussion-between-prashanth-edige-and-jerry-msft).

Comment: Sharepoint Date is 9/11/2018 and my api accepts this 2018-11-10

Comment: reverse is not working since reverse of 9/11/2018 is 2018-11-9, it should be 2018-09-11

Comment: var date="9/11/2018"; var newdate = date.split("/");var year=newdate[2];var day=newdate[1];var month=newdate[0]; var final=year+"-"+month+"-"+day;

Comment: How can I store the time value in a variable when I select the time in sharepoint list?