SP2013/2019: JQuery to Count Date Field Changes
I need a way to track the number of times [ExtensionDate], a date field changes in a SP List. I would love JQuery if possible. The count should be stored in a number field [ExtensionDateChanges]
I reviewed this Counting Field Changes it does not give me what I need, and I'm comfortable with JQuery.
Thank you!

Any ideas?  Thanks

Have you at least tried to create a solution yourself?

Here's my crude attempt, which is not functioning:
$(document).ready(function() {
// Get reference to Extension Date field

var extensionField =   $("input[title='Extension Date']");

var counterField = $("input[title='Change Counter']");


extensionField.change(function() {

    // Get current counter value

    var currentCount = counterField.val() || 0;

    
    // Increment counter

    var newCount = parseInt(currentCount) + 1;

    
    // Update count field

    counterField.val(newCount);

});

});

(sorry, not sure how to add code to a comment box. Not same as the query box)

Got it! I borrowed from here:  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/248724/sharepoint-date-field-value-using-jquery
